# Intermittent Error with YouTube API: Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com'

Tags: youtube-api

I am getting an intermittent error when attempting to use the YouTube API to retrieve playlist and video information.  I am using the PHP client.  Here is the full error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com'' in /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/IO/Curl.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/IO/Abstract.php(136): Google_IO_Curl->executeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php(60): Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#3 /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#5 /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php(590): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#6 /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(228): Google_Client->execute(Objec in /Test/libs/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/IO/Curl.php on line 115
```

Also, here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey("*****************");

$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
$results = $service->playlists->listPlaylists("snippet", array("channelId" => "UCkyQHj9ceKEVZR2qO0LUUdg", "maxResults" => 50));
$results = $service->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems("snippet", array("playlistId" => "PL2Kceei6lZdpFRvkRyQMStS0UknLE3mKV", "maxResults" => 50));
```

The error is not consistent.  It does not happen all of the time.  When it does, which is often, I have to refresh my browser a couple of times, and then it works.

Has anyone encountered this?